# failed to retrieve amazon glacier archive

Tags: amazon-glacier

I try to retrieve archive from amazon glacier using .Net SDK I have initiate archive retrieval job successfully but when I try to get the job output the server returns Internal server error (500) - An error has occurred and the request cannot be processed.

any help please

Comment: Did you receive notification that the retrieval job completed?  Does your application make other requests that work just fine, or possibly also produce an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 means an Amazon bug. Contact support on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ and specify request IDs and request/response dumps.